# How to Install older version of Meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

Ciao Paolo,

thanks for the amazing work with meshlab,

I was trying OccNet, and I run into this issue

```
output mesh  /home/xxx/Documents/occupancy_networks/external/mesh-fusion/examples/3_out/chair_0893.off
Apply FilterScript: '/home/xxx/Documents/occupancy_networks/external/mesh-fusion/simplification.mlx'
FilterScript
Reading filter with name Simplification: Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation
Starting Script of 1 actionsfilter: Simplification: Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation
meshlabserver: ./src/meshlabserver/mainserver.cpp:375: bool MeshLabServer::script(MeshDocument&, const QString&, FILE*): Assertion `parameterSet.paramList.size() == required.paramList.size()' failed.
```

Assertion `parameterSet.paramList.size() == required.paramList.size()' failed

https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/345

I was wondering if I should install a previous version, or is there a better way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was that meshlabserver is only available in 2020.03 that can be installed with `sudo apt meshlab.` no need to install previous versions

you need to change that specific simplification.mlx file to match the exact filter, you can follow instruction here https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/345

Answer (score 2):

You can find the older versions of MeshLab in the [Releases Tab](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases)

Comment: Thanks @rockcat, how can install in Linux? Sudo apt xxxx?

Comment: What if I need something before the 2016?

Comment: Sudo apt install meshlab will install the version in the repository, so you can't control it

Comment: Previous to 2016? You could use the package from a old linux distro.